# Append to slice of interfaces

Tags: pointers, go, interface, slice

I'm writing a document generator. There is a `DocumentItem` interface - this is part of the document.

```
type DocumentItem interface {
    compose() string
}
```

For example, a document consists of paragraphs and tables.

```
type Paragraph struct {
    text string
}
type Table struct{}
```

The `Paragraph` and `Table` types correspond to the `DocumentItem` interface.

```
func (p *Paragraph) compose() string {
    return ""
}

func (t *Table) compose() string {
    return ""
}
```

The `Document` type contains the `content []*DocumentItem` field.

```
type Document struct {
    content []*DocumentItem
}
```

I'm looking for a way that would allow `NewParagraph()` and `NewTable()` functions to create the necessary data types and add them to the `content` field.

```
func (d *Document) NewParagraph() *Paragraph {
    p := Paragraph{}
    d.content = append(d.content, &p)
    return &p
}

func (d *Document) NewTable() *Table {
    t := Table{}
    d.content = append(d.content, &t)
    return &t
}
```

I use an slice of interface pointers in order to be able to modify the data in the corresponding variables after they are included in the document.

```
func (p *Paragraph) SetText(text string) {
    p.text = text
}

func main() {
    d := Document{}
    p := d.NewParagraph()
    p.SetText("lalala")
    t := d.NewTable()
    // ...    
}
```

But I get compiler errors:

```
cannot use &p (type *Paragraph) as type *DocumentItem in append
cannot use &t (type *Table) as type *DocumentItem in append
```

If I cast the types to an `DocumentItem` interface, I will lose access to specific functions, which in the case of one type may differ from the other. For example, add text to a paragraph and add a row of cells and then add text to cell for the table.

Is it possible at all?

Full example at https://play.golang.org/p/uJfKs5tJ98

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use pointer to interface, only a slice of interfaces:

```
content []DocumentItem
```

If the dynamic value wrapped in the interface value is a pointer, you lose nothing, you will be able to modify the pointed object.

This was the only thing that had to be changed. To verify, I added printing at the end:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", p)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F21ynmMrEx)):

```
&{text:lalala}
```